# Dynamically inputting values in a structure and printing these values

Tags: c, loops, struct

I wrote this code for a structure stud, that will input the number of students whose record is to be stored, and then print the same. I'm not sure where exactly I'm going wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct stud{
int id;
char name[50];
float points;
}s[1000];

int main(){

     int i,n;
     scanf("%d",&n);

     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         scanf("%d",&s[i].id);
         scanf("%c",s[i].name);
         scanf("%f",&s[i].points);
        }
       
       for(i=0;i<n;i++){
           printf("ID: %d\n",s[i].id);
           printf("First Name: %c\n",s[i].name);
           printf("Points: %f\n",s[i].points);
        }

       return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `scanf("%c",s[i].name);` - why are you only reading a single character into the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 scanf("%c",s[i].name);
```

to at least

```
 scanf("%49s",s[i].name);
```

and the same for `printf()` call also. `%c` is for a single `char`, for a string, you'd need `%s`. Also, don't forget to check the return value of `scanf()` for success.

That being said, better to use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) for user input. Something like

```
  if( fgets (s[i].name, sizeof(s[i].name), stdin) != NULL ) { /*......*/ }
```

Comment: thank you, that did the trick, the reason i used the %c identifier is because i'm always a little confused between the strings and chars, I know that strings don't exist in C so i always think defining a character array should solve that issue.